# Convertir de caracter a entero y viceversa

Tags: java

Necesito cambiar el índice de las filas a letras ej:
0,1,2,3 = A,B,C,D. las columnas si en números.

Estoy simulando las sillas de una sala de cine creando reservas. entonces debe ser en formato letra/numero, ej: A1=0,1  B3=1,3.

main:

```
 public static String sillas[][]=new String[4][10];
public static String reserva= "*";
public static void main(String[] args) {      



   for(int f=0;f<4;f++){


        for(int c=0;c<10;c++){
            sillas[f][c]=" ";                
            }

    }
    menu();

    mostrarSillas();





}
```

les muestro la matriz actual:

```
public static void mostrarSillas(){
    System.out.println();
    int f,c;
    for(f=0;f<4;f++){

        for(c=0;c<2;c++){
        System.out.print("|_"+sillas[f][c]+"_|");


        }
        if(c==2){
            System.out.print("        ");                
        }

        for(c=3;c<7;c++){
        System.out.print("|_"+sillas[f][c]+"_|");


        }

        if(c==7){
            System.out.print("        ");                
        }

        for(c=8;c<10;c++){
        System.out.print("|_"+sillas[f][c]+"_|");


        }
        System.out.println(); 

    }
```

imprimiendo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora el codigo de reserva:

```
public static boolean asignarPuesto( ){
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String seleccion;
    System.out.println("Digite silla a reservar:");
    seleccion=scn.next();
    sillas[seleccion.charAt(0)][seleccion.charAt(1)]=reserva;
    return false;

}
```

no logro saber como poder llamar al index en formato letra/numero.

gracias.

Answer (score 3):

En Java, la conversión **desde** *carácter* **a** *entero* es **directa**:

```
char c = 'a';
char c2 = '1';

int a = c;
int b = c2;

System.out.println( a );
System.out.println( b );
```

> 97
> 49

A la inversa, **desde** *entero* **a** *carácter*, pasa por realizar una promoción del valor:

```
int a = 97;
int b = 49;

char c = (char)a;
char c2 = (char)b;

System.out.println( c );
System.out.println( c2 );
```

> a
> 1

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero aun no me funciona, como renombro las filas de la matriz en Letra?, 0=A,1=B,2=C. probe con sus aportes pero no me deja.

Comment: @DavidAlejandroLarrota `println( (char)( numero + 'A' ) );`

Answer (score 1):

De char a int:

```
char c='a';
System.out.println((int)c);
```

De entero a caracter:

```
int i=10;
System.out.println((char)i);
```

Debes basarte en el codigo ascii de los caracteres, por ejemplo:

```
if(c>=97 && c<=122){
return c-97;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero aun no me funciona, como renombro las filas de la matriz en Letra?, 0=A,1=B,2=C. probé con sus aportes pero no me deja.